# What maps sizes did old 2D RTS games like C&C and WarCraft support?

Tags: tilemap, rts

I'm looking for the size (in tiles) of the maps for the old 2D games Command and Conquer and Warcraft 1 and 2.

Comment: [C&C](http://vgmaps.com/Atlas/PC/index.htm#CommandConquerTiberianDawn), [Warcraft 1](http://vgmaps.com/Atlas/PC/index.htm#WarCraftOrcsHumans), [Warcraft 2](http://vgmaps.com/Atlas/PC/index.htm#WarCraftIITidesOfDarkness). Enjoy.

Comment: This sort of seems like it might be a bit more on-topic at Gaming, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It could be relevant if you read it as "what is a good map size for gameplay?". If you use those games as mental basis for your own development it's good to know the exact specs. But really, this question should be phrased differently.

Comment: It is for my own RTS yes but I don't need any more input than the actual sizes (smallest and biggest) that is why I only asked for the size, not for help. Thanks anyway though ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about historical industry trivia.

Comment: But useful information when making RTS games.
OTOH I really don't understand how gamedev should be useful anymore so you are maybe right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Warcraft II has maps in the range 32x32 to 128x128. And given that the large maps generally feel pretty large I'd say that you don't actually need more than that. Usually going larger pretty much just means that you have to have stuff fill more on the map.

Answer (score 3):

Command & Conquer - Tiberian Dawn supports up to 64 x 64. Tile size is 24px x 24px.
Red Alert 1 - The Aftermath supports up to 128 x 128.